# Fortran program manager linking to externally installed modules

Tags: fortran, gfortran, netcdf, fpm

I am beginner in Fortran programming. I found fpm very easy and friendly to build Fortran projects. But I am having a hard time of linking my project to externally installed modules. The fpm documentation mentioned the linking procedure only briefly without an example . Could someone please help me translating the following standard terminal build command to fpm build command?

```
gfortran  main.f90  -o  main  -I/usr/local/include  -L/usr/local/lib  -lnetcdff
```

In short, the `main.f90` file uses a netcdf module installed in `usr/local` folder.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: We should distinguish getting the module files recognized by the compiler and linking with the actual binary of the library by the linker. These steps are quite independent.  Do you have problems with both steps? Did you have some specific errors when you tried something?

Comment: The standard terminal command given in the question compiles my program without any error. But I want to compile the file using  `fpm`  for example like `fpm build`. But I need to link the file to the installed module.

Comment: Yes, but there are two different issues here. You have to solve them in fpm both. 1. compile the code with the module files in the include directory, 2. link the object files or libraries in the lib directory. Do you have problems with both of them in fpm? did you try something? Did you get any output?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Yes, the module files in the include directory are compiled. Regarding issue no. 2, how can I link the libraries in the lib directory to the ´main.f90´ file using fpm?

Comment: And what is your current fpm configuration?

Comment: Please note that I am not an fpm user myself. There is a chapter about linking external libraries in the documentation https://fpm.fortran-lang.org/en/spec/manifest.html#link-external-libraries You should use `link=["netcdff"]`. I know you can specify custom compiler flags, but I do not know how the directory for the library is specified. But it would really help if you could show your current effort. Finally, please note that the bigest fpm experts hang around at the Fortran Discourse site.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I will take my question to the Discourse site

Comment: Please come back with the result. It would have really helped if you did show us what kind of errors you have.